# DynamoDB Cloudformation Permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I currently have the following cloudformation .yaml file:

```
Resources:
  DynamoTable:
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  Properties:
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

How do I give other resources permission to query this table?

Comment: Did you mean how do you give other resources/IAMs permission to query the table?

Comment: @CharlesLandau sorry I’m new to this. I guess so, I need an application running in an ecs cluster to be able to query the table. At the moment it errors out saying that it doesn’t have Query Permission. I figured I had to set the table permission to be queryable by *.

Comment: Create an iam role with permissions for the dynamodb. Use this role as the ecs service role.

Comment: @vishnunarayanan thanks, but I don’t know how to do that. I know I should be creating an IAM role but I don’t know how to structure it/ point it to the table/ give the ecs service that role. Could you write an example?

Comment: [Here is some documentation on adding permission for DynamoDB access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html)

Comment: @Deiv thanks, I’ll try it.

Comment: @Deiv, I took a look at it and I don't understand where I am supposed to put the code. Do I just insert "Version: "Version": "2012-10-17", Statement: ..." at the bottom or the top of my file?

Comment: If you're using the console, then simply add the policy through the IAM - Policies section, and then attach it to your resource through it's policy section. If you are doing it through cloudformation, you can do so using [the iam policy resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html), where the policy document is the JSON containing the version/statement/etc.

Comment: You can then use !Ref to attach the policy to the resource in the yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Resources:
  Service:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        ...
        ...
        TaskPolicyArn: !Ref ThisServicePolicy

  DynamoTable:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        ...
        ...
        ...

  ThisServicePolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: SomePolicyName
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: 
              - "dynamodb:GetItem"
              - "dynamodb:BatchGetItem"
              - "dynamodb:Query"
            Resource: "*"
```

Comment: It would be probably better to limit the "Resource" to a specific tables. Also, the policy should be connected to a role that will be used, see example in this post https://runkiss.blogspot.com/2021/10/create-aws-dynamodb-using.html